# Deprecated functions is deprecated ereg_replace() and eregi()

Tags: php

following two lines are giving warning,

```
if (eregi($patt,$v,$res))
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /classes/xtpl.php on line 50
```

and

```
$copy=ereg_replace("\{".$v."\}","$var",$copy);

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /classes/xtpl.php on line 25
```

i have try to use `preg_match()` in following way, but unable to solve the issue

```
$copy=preg_match("\{".$v."\}","$var",$copy);
if (preg_match($patt,$v,$res))
```

please give some idea

Answer (score 1):

These functions are not recommended since PHP 5.3.
Use preg_replace instead of ereg_replace and preg_match instead of eregi.
You may find the necessary information regarding these functions here-
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: i have replaced ereg_replace with preg_replace, and eregi with preg_match, preg_replace worked fine, but with use of preg_match i am getting blank page

Answer (score 0):

you must use delimeters

```
preg_match('/'.$v.'/',$var,$copy);
```

http://us.php.net/preg_match

Comment: after this, i m getting blank page